# Something like setCell for form edit in JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Ok, I've been looking for a answer in alot of @Oleg 's answers  but I couldn't find anything.  I have this grid, where a can edit in line, in some fields, I'm working with autocomplete and when I select some item, I use setCell, to write the value in another field. My column model is something like this...

```
{ name: 'Label', index: 'Label', width: 100, align: 'Center', sorttype: "string",
    editable: true, editrules: { required: true },
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    PageMethods.ObtLabels(request.term, function (data) {
                        var tiposCliente = (typeof data) == 'string' ?
                                           eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
                        response(tiposCliente);
                    }, fnLlamadaError);
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var rowid = $('#pendientes').getGridParam('selrow');
                    **jQuery('#pendientes').setCell(rowid, 'LabelId', ui.item.id);**
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

this work fine when edit and add inline but, when I want to add or edit a row with the Form, I can not write the value in another field.

I don't know if my question is clear. I just want to write something in the "X" field, depending the opcion I chose in the "Y" field. All this using the Form.

If someone can help me it would be great.

Thanks a lot !

UPDATE AND SOLUTION:

I Just add the next line to my code:

$('input#LabelId').val(ui.item.id);

And its work, with that I write in the LAbelId the selected item's value

in the end el code for my column with autocomplete is something like this:

```
{ name: 'Label', index: 'Label', width: 100, align: 'Center', sorttype: "string",
    editable: true, editrules: { required: true },
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    PageMethods.ObtLabels(request.term, function (data) {
                        var tiposCliente = (typeof data) == 'string' ?
                                           eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
                        response(tiposCliente);
                    }, fnLlamadaError);
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var rowid = $('#pendientes').getGridParam('selrow');
                    jQuery('#pendientes').setCell(rowid, 'LabelId', ui.item.id);
                    **$('input#LabelId').val(ui.item.id);**
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: It is not clear for me whether `'LabelId'` column is editable or not? Do you use single select mode of `multiselect: true`?

Comment: Yes LabelId is editable, and it is hidden too...but I already found the answer, I just add this this row....

$('input#LabelId').val(ui.item.id);

And its work, with that I write in the LAbelId the selected item's value...

Thanks Alot !! for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, I just Add the next line...

```
$('input#ClienteProveedor').val(ui.item.id);
```

this write the ui.item.id to the "Y" field that I wanted.